# Регулярные выражения на смайлики

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярное выражение исключающее из текста любые смайлики ☺, но чтобы символы (например (),?/ и все остальные) были разрешены?

2 Вопрос. В Unity-приложении на андроид не отображаются смайлики. Если их написать, то выводится просто текст, пропуская смайлики.
Можно ли как-то это исправить в скриптах через dnSpy?

Answer (score 2):

В C# для регулярного выражения можно задать [группу символов юникода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions).
Думаю вам подойдет либо нахождение такой группы символов, которая отвечает за смайлики, либо использование всех остальных групп символов в сочетании с негативным поиском.